# How can I extrude a egde into the middle of another egde?

Tags: modeling, workflow, vertices

I am learning blender. But I am having some problems. I'm trying to extrude a egde and add the end as a point in another egde. I made this to illustrate what I want to do: The 3 green lines are what I am trying to add.
On the right hand side you can see the other 2 areas I want do to do a similar process with. So, kind of fixing a part of a egde loop which got cut off when I deleted some vertices
[image: Problem]

Comment: Select both vertices and press "J". It'll do the rest :)

Comment: @TLousky Thanks a lot, quick follow up question, how would I do something like this: http://i.imgur.com/lQUaCVU.png

Comment: Select the edge that doesn't have a central vertex, and split it at the center via "W" --> Subdivide. The go to vertex selection mode, and select the new vertex at the center of the freshly split edge, and the other vertex at the center of the 2nd edge, and connect them both with "J".

Comment: @TLousky could you please add your comments as an answer?

Comment: Stacker, sure, will do in a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender has a built in tool to join faraway verts such as these, and to automatically create all the connecting edges. The tool is called "Connect Vertex Path", and is assigned the shortcut key <kbd>J</kbd>.

I find it to be a pretty essential modeling tool I personally discovered rather late.

All you need to do to use it, is to select two verts, then press <kbd>J</kbd>:

[image]